# "el.closest is not a function at getScrollTarget", using Quasar Framework (Vue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My modal consists of cards which works fine.  Now I want to have the 'active' card at the top of the viewport when the modal opens.  I am trying to do this using `getScrollTarget` and  `setScrollPosition` but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.closest is not a function at getScrollTarget     (quasar.esm.js?8bfb:1384)
     at VueComponent.open (ModalTest.vue?4a7f:120) 
     at VueComponent.boundFn [as open] (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:165)
     at VueComponent.openModal (Maplayout.vue?1988:60)
     at VueComponent.boundFn [as openModal] (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:165)
     at Vue$3.eval (Maplayout.vue?1988:47)
     at Vue$3.Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:2202)
     at Object.$emit (quasar.esm.js?8bfb:198)
    at HTMLElement.emitEventFunction (util.js?93ee:587)
```

The modal component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <q-modal ref="myModal" maximized>
      <q-modal-layout class="scroll">
        <div class="layout-padding">
          <q-card inline
                  center
                  style="min-width: 90vw"
                  v-for="test in tests"
                  :key="tests.id"
          >
            <q-card-media>
              <img :src="test.getAttribute('image')">
            </q-card-media>
            <q-card-main>
              <div>{{ test.getAttribute('myAttribute') }}</div>
            </q-card-main>
          </q-card>
        </div>
      </q-modal-layout>
    </q-modal>
</template>
<script>
import {
  QCard,
  QCardMain,
  QCardMedia,
  QModal,
  QModalLayout,
  scroll
} from 'quasar'
const {getScrollTarget, setScrollPosition} = scroll
export default {
  name: 'myModal',
  components: {
    QCard,
    QCardMain,
    QCardMedia,
    QModal,
    QModalLayout,
    scroll
  },
  computed: {
    ...myState({
      tests: state => state.mymodule.tests
    })
  },
  methods: {
    open () {
      this.$refs.myModal.open()
      const element = document.getElementById('feature-listing').getElementsByClassName('item-image active')
      console.log('element: ', element)
      setScrollPosition(getScrollTarget(element), 0, 200)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The output of the console.log gives following about the `element` that is active in the console:

`[div#98729.item-image.js-fade.my-quick-fade-in.active, 98729: undefined]`

I do not quite understand the 'undefined' part... (the length of the array is 1..., so maybe not relevant or something...?!), as the div can be opened in the console and looks good to me.

I am trying to follow [this in the docs](http://quasar-framework.org/components/scrolling-utils.html). I also looked into the code for the polyfill for 'closest' [here](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/669a93239c17ab960917f9c87198e5a315b97d44/src/features/polyfills.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of error is that no valid div is referenced. When I use element[0] it starts working.

Furthermore scroll methods in the modal will only give value after modal properly opened, so need to use the @open event. See [this](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/986) for details.